Admob open ads misplaced video on Android
I am developing Android apps and add Admob ads into my app. When the open ads is showing video, the video is misplaced, it goes to upper side. How to resolve this. It happened on android device.
This project can reproduce the issue. https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/java/admob/AppOpenExample

Anyone has ever meet this case? Is there any workaround
